# r/ how to apply lowess smoothing to variables that are initially unordered in data frame

Tags: r, smoothing

For Iris-data:

```
i <- iris[,1:4] # numerical variables in Iris-data
ord_i <- order(i[,1]) # order data frame by variable 1 ascending order 
low_i <- lowess(i[ord_i,1], f=1/10)[2] # compute lowess for ordered variable 1
i[ord_i,1] <- low_i # insert new values to original data
```

is successful. I tried and failed to generalize this into a function:

```
func1 <- function(x){
  func1_aux <- function(x,y){
  ord_x <- order(x[,y])
  low_y <- lowess(x[ord_x, y], f=1/10)[2]}    
apply(x, 2, func1_aux)}

func1(i)
Error in x[, y] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I suspect the problem is in how variable name y and data frame x come 
from apply to func1_aux.

Any advice how to fix this or smarter way to do the task? Thanks!

Comment: Insert `browser()` after your `func1_aux` line, source your `func1` function and go through the code, step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you would want to do this, but here's one way to independently sort each column of a data frame and fit a lowess smooth to it:

```
i <- iris[, 1:4]
k <- apply(i, 2, function(x) lowess(x[order(x)], f=1/10)[[2]][match(x, x[order(x)])])
```

Using the double brackets, `[[2]]`, ensures that the result, `k`, is a matrix rather than a list.  Although this approach fits a lowess smooth to each column sorted independently, in order to keep the results in the same order as the original data frame `i`, you need to "*unsort*" it.  That's what the `[match(...)]` part of the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. I will study match-function.